# ekf_localization compute heading from gps motion?

Tags: ros, gps, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My magnetometer is not working so great here, so I'm thinking about estimating mobile robot heading from changes in GPS location (as I think is used in car satnavs to get the heading).     My question is, how to integrate this with the ekf_localization system?    Should I write my own node which takes NMEA in and writes out headings, and fuse them into ekf_localization,   or is ekf_localization or some other existing library node already set up to do this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209982/ekf_localization-compute-heading-from-gps-motion?/) by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2015-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ekf_localization_node` does not handle this. You're not the first person to want that kind of functionality in a node, so if there are no others, you might consider writing one and releasing it. Note, however, that some GPS devices provide heading based on differentiated positions, and their ROS drivers would likely fill out those fields in the messages they produce.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0